# Django: Where generic forms like LoginView renders functions dictionary fill and how can I change it

Tags: python, django, httprequest, render, loginview

I use LoginView class in Django. We can use this class as login view with a HTML template, like below:

 urls:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
path('', LoginView.as_view(), {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
]
```

login.html:

```
<head>
   <title>test<title>
   {% load static %}
</head>
<body>
   <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
   </form>
</body>
```

my question is where renders function dictionary or httprequest fill? and how can I change, `form.as_p` to `login_form.as_p`, for example?

Comment: I'm so sorry because I'm not good in English and I wish I could have written clearly understandable question

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from  [Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Comment: I've read it and couldn't find what I want there ... if you know where is it, link me precision (I checked above link and didn't find out yet) ...

Answer (score 0):

You must use custom login view like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """Insert the form into the context dict."""
    if 'login_form' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['login_form'] = self.get_form()
    # Another your context
    return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Tnx, but I don't understand what is context dict?!

Comment: @exception kwargs is context dict.